# JavaScript not being executed in a section under Razor

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I've managed to get the following to execute properly, meaning that I've set the renering etc. correctly. I do get to see the alert window.

```
@{ Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Default.cshtml"; }
<h1>Eye candies</h1>

@section Footie
{
  <script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Ola!");
  </script>
}
```

However, when I change that to execute a different script, showing a cool globe with visitors, I see nothing, nada, ziltch! No error, no nothing. Just empty page.

When I paste the URL into a browser, I get a JS source code back, so I'm assuming that this part works. But I have no ideas left how to investigate it further.

```
@section Footie
{
  <script src="@Url.Content("//ra.revolvermaps.com/0/0/5.js?i=0w5jyvctga6&amp;m=0&amp;s=180&amp;c=ff0000&amp;cr1=ffffff")"
          async="async"
          type="text/javascript"></script>
}
```

I've added a static HTML page and pasted in the script there. Works like a charm! So it's definitely related to script execution under a view in MVC (or possible Razor syntax).

Suggestions?

Comment: ~/Views/Shared/_Default.cshtml contains ````RenderSection("Footie",false)````?

Comment: please get a inspect element of your page in your browser.and tell us what has been loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the url you are passing to the `Url.Content` method

```
@Url.Content("//ra.revolvermaps.com/0/0/5.js?i=0w5jyvctga6&amp;m=0&amp;s=180
                                                            &amp;c=ff0000&amp;cr1=ffffff")
```

In the url, the `&` are already encoded to `&amp;` Url.Content method is going to encode the `&` again and you will get the result as

```
"//ra.revolvermaps.com/0/0/5.js?i=0w5jyvctga6&amp;amp;m=0&amp;amp;s=180&amp;amp;
                                                              c=ff0000&amp;amp;cr1=ffffff"
```

Now you have `&amp;amp;`  :)

The solution is to either not use the `Url.Content()` method

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ra.revolvermaps.com/0/0/5.js?i=0w5jyvctga6&amp;
                        m=0&amp;s=180&amp;c=ff0000&amp;cr1=ffffff" async="async"></script>
```

or do not encode the url passing to `Url.Content()` method let the method take care of encoding it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("//ra.revolvermaps.com/0/0/5.js
               ?i=0w5jyvctga6&m=0&s=180&amp;c=ff0000&cr1=ffffff")" async="async"></script>
```